# Every compact set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Does this proof work?

Pf(contrapositive)

Suppose A is not bounded.

Then $\mathbb{R} - A$ is bounded

Thus for some $p \in \mathbb{R}-A$, and for every $\epsilon > 0$, the interval

$(p-\epsilon, p+\epsilon) \cap A \neq \emptyset$

Let $U_n = \mathbb{R} - [p - \frac{1}{n}, p + \frac{1}{n}]$

$A \subset \cup^{n=1}_{\infty}U_n$ is bounded

Comment: If $A$ is unbounded, then $\mathbb{R}-A$ is not necessarily bounded.  Let $A=[0,\infty)$.

Comment: use $(-n,n)$ to form an open cover of $A$ with no finite subcover. Do not consider the complement of $A$ it is not relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the complement of an unbounded set need not be bounded. For instance, if $A = [0,\infty)$ then $\mathbb R \setminus A = (-\infty,0)$ is also unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a cover of the real numbers that consists of bounded sets only, like the one suggested by Mirko. Compactness implies that a finite number of these bounded sets cover $A.$