# Every compact set $A \in \mathbb{R}$ is bounded

Tags: linear-algebra

My previous proof unclear if it is perfectly fine:

[Every compact set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548326/every-compact-set-a-subset-mathbbr-is-bounded)

**Proof**

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ be compact and not bounded.

Then for $(-n,n) \in A$ and every $\epsilon > 0, A \not\subset U_n$

Then $\cup^{\infty}_{n=1}U_n(-n,n)$ is an open cover of A.

Also $U_{n_{k}} = 1,.....,j$ is finite sub cover of $\cup^{\infty}_{n=1}U_n$.

Then $A \subset \cup^{j}_{n=1}U_n(-n,n)$

But $\cup^{j}_{n=1}U_{n_{k}}(-n,n) = U_{n_{j}}$ and $ A \not\subset U_{n_{k}}$ is not bounded.

This is contradiction. Thus A is bounded.

Comment: Sure, this looks fine. You can subtract two lines and avoid the proof by contradiction as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $r>0$ then $X=\cup _{x\in X} B(x,r)$.Since $X$ is compact then $\exists x_1,x_2,...,x_n $ such that $X=\cup_{i=1}^n B(x_i,r)$

Let $R=\max\{d(x_i,x_j):1\leq i,j\leq n\}$

For $a,b \in X\implies a\in B(x_i,r);b\in B(x_j,r)$ for some $i,j$ $\implies d(a,b)\leq d(x_i,a)+d(x_i,x_j)+d(x_j,b)\leq r+r+R=R+2r$(independent of $x\in X$)

Hence $X$ is bounded.